# Replicate list by another list's number of items

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to make this:

```
times([x, x], [1, 5, 9, 8], Result).
```

The second list is replicated by the number of elements in the first one.

The result is : `[1, 5, 9, 8, 1, 5, 9, 8]`

I've tried this but is not working properly:

```
times( [ ], _, [ ] ) :- !.
times( [ _ | List1 ], List2, Result ) :-    append( [], List2, Result ),
                                            times( List1, List2, Result ).
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *The second list is multiplied by the number of elements in the first one.* You mean replicated not multiplied? Using an example with all identical elements isn't the best illustration of what the predicate needs to do.

Comment: replicated, sorry.

Comment: What is the intended result of `times([a,3], [d,e,7]).`?

Comment: [ d, e, 7, d, e, 7 ]. @  `times([], _, _).` i've just put it there to stop the recurssion.

Comment: The rule, `times([], _, _).` says that the empty list times anything is anything else which doesn't seem logical, does it? For example, `times([], [a,b], foo(27)).` succeeds. What result should lead to success?

Comment: i've edited my previous reply. any idea to achieve my goal?

Comment: You don't "just put in a rule to stop recursion". It needs to be just as logical as the rest of the predicate. One thing you need to do is fix that rule.

Comment: i think i fixed it now.

Comment: A couple of other points... (1) you don't need the cut. (2) in your other clause, you have `append( [], List2, Result )`. If you append `[]` to `List2`, you just get `List2`. So that doesn't do anything. It's the same as unifying `List2` with `Result`, `List2 = Result`. Then you have `times( List1, List2, Result )` which wants to bind `Result` in the recursive call. This will only succeed if the result is `List2`. Think in terms of a rule: `times([_|List1], List2, Result) :- ...` says that *`Result` is the result of `[_|List1]` times `List2` if...*. If what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you do not need your cut in the base case. It unnecessarily prunes the solution search:

```
replicate([], _, []).   % The empty list is the result of replicating any list by []
```

Then your recursive rule, `replicate([_|List1], List2, Result)` seems to have a reasonable format/head. But you have logic issues in the body. If you were to describe the logic, it would not make sense. In particular, you're using `Result` in two different places for two different meanings, and that will result in unexpected failure. The predicate just needs to be thought out logically for what it means:

> `Result` is the replication of `List2` by `[_|List1]` *if* `SubResult` is the replication of `List2` by `List1` and `Result` is the result of appending `SubResult` to `List2`.

Note the use of a "subresult" (`SubResult`) here which is distinguished from the main result (`Result`). It's important that these be different variables.

If you write that as Prolog, you get:

```
replicate([_|List1], List2, Result) :-
    replicate(List1, List2, SubResult),
    append(List2, SubResult, Result).
```

I didn't test this, but this should basically do it. You should try it and resolve any residual issues yourself as part of your Prolog learning process. I also did not consider whether there's a more effective approach to the overall problem but am just resolving your issues with your current approach.

---

Another would be to use `maplist/2` and `append/2`. You can use `maplist/3` to get a list of lists, then use `append/2` to get your result:

```
replicate(List1, List2, Result) :-
    length(List1, Len),
    length(R1, Len),
    maplist(=(List2), R1),
    append(R1, Result).
```

---

With a little more thought, this can be solved using simple recursive list handling. In this case, you would recursively unify the head of the result with the head of each element in the second list, then continue this process for each element in the first list.

```
replicate(Rep, List, Res) :-
    replicate(Rep, List, List, Res).

replicate([], _, _, []).
replicate([R|Rs], List, [X|Xs], [X|Res]) :-
    replicate([R|Rs], List, Xs, Res).
replicate([R|Rs], List, [], Res) :-
    replicate(Rs, List, List, Res).
```

Answer (score 1):

We can literally substitute the second list for each element in the first, then call `append/2` (SWI Prolog has one):

```
nreplicate( Xs, Ys, Result) :-
  maplist( subst(Ys), Xs, Zs),
  append( Zs, Result ).

subst(Ys, _, Ys).
```

Comment: s(_) Ah yes, much better than my `append/2` hack.

Comment: @lurker why it's the same `append/2` hack, :) I just "shortcutted" around the `length`. I like this `[A,A,...,A], A=x` trick, but here the `A=` could be fused into the list creation itself.

Comment: Hah you're technically correct. I should have said `length/2` hack. I didn't like using `length/2` that way when I wrote it... It just felt icky.

Comment: ah, yes. indeed, that's what pushed me to post this.

Comment: on the one hand, in retrospect, the proper title for this question is "replace each element in a list with another value (which happens to be a list)" and then this code is a direct translation; on the other hand looking at your solution with the two `length` goals to create the equally-long list, a. these two goals are interchangeable, b. hence they could execute concurrently, independently, c.hence can be fused into one call to a fused predicate which is found by c. each `length` call being replaced with its source and numbers with their symbolic Peano encoding,

Comment: d. so that we eventually get  `equally_long/2 = maplist(unrelated)` where `unrelated(_,_).` and the two consecutive maplists can be again fused into one maplist with a fused predicate `related13(A,_,A).`. What I'm getting at is this imaginary automatic program transformation system, which I'd expect the smart people in academia to work on for the last 40 years, and they didn't, for some reason. Or maybe they did? I realize this is not as easy as with this one example, but ...